# Cells Don't Resize On Custom CollectionView Flow Layout, Should Have Different Size Each

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am following [an old tutorial](https://codentrick.com/create-a-tag-flow-layout-with-uicollectionview/) about how to make a tag flow system on collection view. I have managed to display the full labels with different sizes each, but I am struggling to make the cells resize themselves. I am a beginner in Swift/Xcode so the error must be silly, but I can't figure it out.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://codentrick.com/create-a-tag-flow-layout-with-uicollectionview/) but mine doesn't work. I have changed a little bit according to what Xcode recommended because the syntax there is a bit old. I think I might have misunderstood something.

[I have uploaded the project to GitHub](https://github.com/igormuba/SwiftTagFlowLayout), but what I think is the issue is the following:

This global variable is supposed to be a cell for an overwritten function to check the size:

```
var sizingCell: TagCell?
```

On the `viewDidLoad()` I grab the cell with

```
self.sizingCell = (cellNib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil) as NSArray).firstObject as! TagCell
```

And on the extension

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource{
...
}
```

I have the following functions to adjust the size of the cell (from the tutorial)

```
func configureCell(cell: TagCell, forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath){
    let tag = TAGS[indexPath.row]
    cell.tagName.text = tag
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
    self.configureCell(cell: self.sizingCell!, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    return self.sizingCell!.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
}
```

I expected for different rows to be able to have different amount of tags (like in a flow layout) and each tag cell with a different width. Instead, every cell has the size size, but the tags are allowed to have different sizes.